# Spark 2.1 UDF not getting registered in Spark Jar

Tags: scala, apache-spark, user-defined-functions

I am using a CDH cluster with Spark 2.1 with Scala Version 2.11.8

I have created a UDF inside one of my methods.

When I execute the method in Spark Shell Repl, it works absolutely fine.
However,the same UDF is not able to register when the method is called from a Spark Jar using Spark submit command.

Below is the build.sbt content:

```
name := "newtest"
version := "0.0.2"

scalaVersion := "2.10.5" 

sbtPlugin := true

val sparkVersion = "2.1.0"

mainClass in (Compile, run) := Some("com.testPackage.sq.newsparktest.Test")

 assemblyJarName in assembly := "newtest.jar"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(   
   "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion % "provided",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion % "provided",
  "com.databricks" %% "spark-avro" % "3.2.0",
   "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-hive" % "1.5.0" % "provided",
     "com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk" % "1.0.002"
   )

libraryDependencies +=
     "log4j" % "log4j" % "1.2.15" excludeAll(
       ExclusionRule(organization = "com.sun.jdmk"),
       ExclusionRule(organization = "com.sun.jmx"),
       ExclusionRule(organization = "javax.jms")
     )

resolvers += "SparkPackages" at "https://dl.bintray.com/spark-packages/maven/"
resolvers += Resolver.url("bintray-sbt-plugins", url("http://dl.bintray.com/sbt/sbt-plugin-releases"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)

assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
case x => MergeStrategy.first
}
```

Plugins.SBT as below:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "5.0.1")
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.14.3")
```

Following is the code Snippet that is causing the issue:

```
val timestamp_diff = (endTime: Timestamp, startTime: Timestamp) => {
  (endTime.getTime() - startTime.getTime())
}
 logger.info("Function Created") --------> **This works fine**

    spark.udf.register("timestamp_diff", timestamp_diff )


-----> **The above command causes error as below**
```

Following is the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.reflect.api.JavaUniverse.runtimeMirror(Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;)Lscala/reflect/api/JavaMirrors$JavaMirror;
            at com.testPackage.sq.newsparktest$.main(newsparktest.scala:49)
            at com.testPackage.sq.newsparktest.main(newsparktest.scala)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
            at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:738)
            at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:187)
            at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:212)
            at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:126)
            at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

**Note: As mentioned earlier, the failed command works perfectly well when executed directly on REPL instead of executing through Spark jar**

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a Scala version issue. From the [Spark 2.1 docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/):

> Spark runs on Java 7+, Python 2.6+/3.4+ and R 3.1+. For the Scala API, Spark 2.1.0 uses Scala 2.11. You will need to use a compatible Scala version (2.11.x).

Hence, you may want to use a newer version of Scala:

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.11"
```

Note that Scala `2.12.x` is not yet supported.